# D3 v5 area chart not being generated

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am using v**5.9.7** of d3. I want to create an area chart, but for some reason its showing issue at one place. I have copied the code from one of their online example, but it is not working on my machine.

Here is my code.

```
    const height = 500;
    const width = 800;
    const data = [
      {date: '2007-04-23', value: '93.24'},
      {date: '2007-04-24', value: '95.35'},
      {date: '2007-04-25', value: '98.84'},
      {date: '2007-04-26', value: '99.92'},
      {date: '2007-04-29', value: '99.8'},
      {date: '2007-05-01', value: '99.47'},
      {date: '2007-05-02', value: '100.39'},
      {date: '2007-05-03', value: '100.4'},
      {date: '2007-05-04', value: '100.81'},
      {date: '2007-05-07', value: '103.92'}
    ];

    const x = d3.scaleUtc()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, (d: any) => d.date))
      .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d:any) => d.value)]).nice()
      .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    const curve = d3.curveLinear;

    const area =  d3.area()
      .curve(curve)
      .x((d) => x(d['date']))
      .y0(y(0))
      .y1((d) => y(d['value']));
      console.log(area);

    const xAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))

    const yAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
      .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text('$ Close')
      );

      const svg = d3.select('#ui-area-chart').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr('height', height - margin.bottom - margin.top)
        .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

      svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("d", area);

      svg.append("g")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .call(yAxis);
```

For some reason it is not accepting area in the **d** attribute for path. Here is how it looks in my IDE.
[image]

Any quick help would be appreciated, this issue has already wasted a lot of my time. Anxiously waiting for someone to help. Thanks

Comment: So this is not about the code not running, but about a Typescript error? Try changing `d3.area()` to `d3.area<{ date: string; value: number }>()`

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't in the right format-- both your `.date` and `.value` are strings, where [time scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time-scales) and [linear scales](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales) expect `Date`s and `Number`s, respectively.

To fix this, you can reformat your data

```
    var data = [
      {date: '2007-04-23', value: '93.24'},
      {date: '2007-04-24', value: '95.35'},
      {date: '2007-04-25', value: '98.84'},
      {date: '2007-04-26', value: '99.92'},
      {date: '2007-04-29', value: '99.8'},
      {date: '2007-05-01', value: '99.47'},
      {date: '2007-05-02', value: '100.39'},
      {date: '2007-05-03', value: '100.4'},
      {date: '2007-05-04', value: '100.81'},
      {date: '2007-05-07', value: '103.92'}
    ];
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
    data = data.map(x => ({ date: parseDate(x.date), value: +x.value }));
```

Snippet:

```js
const height = 500;
    const width = 800;
    const margin = {
      left: 40, right: 40, top: 40, bottom: 40
    }
    var data = [
      {date: '2007-04-23', value: '93.24'},
      {date: '2007-04-24', value: '95.35'},
      {date: '2007-04-25', value: '98.84'},
      {date: '2007-04-26', value: '99.92'},
      {date: '2007-04-29', value: '99.8'},
      {date: '2007-05-01', value: '99.47'},
      {date: '2007-05-02', value: '100.39'},
      {date: '2007-05-03', value: '100.4'},
      {date: '2007-05-04', value: '100.81'},
      {date: '2007-05-07', value: '103.92'}
    ];
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
    data = data.map(x => ({ date: parseDate(x.date), value: +x.value }));
    const x = d3.scaleUtc()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.date))
      .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.value)]).nice()
      .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

    const curve = d3.curveLinear;

    const area =  d3.area()
      .curve(curve)
      .x((d) => x(d['date']))
      .y0(y(0))
      .y1((d) => y(d['value']));

    const xAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0))

    const yAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
      .call(g => g.select(".tick:last-of-type text").clone()
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text('$ Close')
      );

      const svg = d3.select('#ui-area-chart').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width - margin.left - margin.right)
        .attr('height', height - margin.bottom - margin.top)
        .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

      svg.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("d", area);

      svg.append("g")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="ui-area-chart" width="960px" height="500px"></div>
```